# How to use same onclick function multiple times in php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I make a .php page which retrieves data from mysql and display it on that .php page each record one by one simple. but the actual problem is when i am clicks links it shows that div and vice versa but, only works on row 1. i know onclick function is unique so, it will calls once. So, i used .querySelector() instead .getElementById(). because whole content inside while loop is comes from database so, id is not works their.Ok,finally comes to the point how,
I call same onclick function for both introduction and for features link (for row 1 and for row 2).("searched to much for solution but nothing happens")

My javascript code :

```
<head>
 <script>
  function ShowIntroduction() 
  {
    document.querySelector(".IntroductionDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector(".FeaturesDiv").style.display = 'none';
  }
  function ShowFeatures() 
  {
    document.querySelector(".IntroductionDiv").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector(".FeaturesDiv").style.display = 'block';
  }
 </script>
</head>
```

My php code :

```
<body>
  <?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
   ob_start();
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'sldb');
    $connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    $database = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());
    $select=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products_page");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($select);

while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
  $id=$userrow['id'];     
  $userintroduction=$userrow['introduction'];
  $userfeatures=$userrow['features'];

echo '
  <div class="MainOuterDiv" style="border:1px solid transparent;">
    <div class="DetailsCircleBtnDiv" >
        <a href="#" onClick="ShowIntroduction();"> Introduction </a>
        <a href="#" onClick="ShowFeatures();" style="margin-left:10px"> Features </a>
    </div> <!--- End of DetailsCircleBtnDiv ----->
    </br>

    <div class="DetailsTextDiv">
        <div class="FeaturesDiv" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <p class="Products-Features-P" >'.$userfeatures.'</p>
        </div></br>
        <div class="IntroductionDiv" style="border:1px solid black;">
            <p id="demo" class="Products-Introductio-P" >'.$userintroduction.'</p>
        </div></br>
    </div> <!--- End of DetailsTextDiv ----->
   </div> <!--- End of MainOuterDiv ----->
   </br>';
}
?>

</body>
```

[image]

When I click on row 1's introduction/Features link works fine but, when use row 2nd's introduction/features link it works for row 1's introduction div and for features div.

Comment: So you need to look at the row you are in and select the class from that row.

Comment: Simply i want to show same div on same link click. But, how ? Any solutions please. !

Comment: @epascarello but how ?

Comment: If I guess it right, you want to show "introduction" and hide "features" when you clic on an item. And vice versa. Is that right ?

Comment: But unable to use id here so i am using classes @JeffreyTroost you have any demo,code please its helpful for me.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared, Parameterized Queries.

Comment: Yes you are right @r4phG. it's sounds simple but i don't think so ?

Comment: Yes @CharlotteDunois surely I remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inline events are a bad idea, just use jQuery since you have it listed

Add class to the anchor

```
<a href="#" class="anchorShow"> Introduction </a>
```

listen for the click

```
$( function () {  //wait for document to be ready
    $(".anchorShow").on("click", function (evt) {  //bind the click event to the anchors
        evt.preventDefault();  //stop click
        var anchor = $(this);  //link that was clicked
        var wrapper = anchor.closest(".MainOuterDiv");  //parent element that wraps content
        wrapper.find(".IntroductionDiv").show();  //show intro
        wrapper.find(".FeaturesDiv").hide();      //hide features
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes i try your code but on link click nothing happanes ! why ?

Comment: Did you bind it on document ready? I updated it to include document ready

Comment: Its also works like a charm thank @epascarello. but i am little bit confused which solution is good.

Comment: I am not a fan of ids, but if you want a lot of ids, you can easily generate them and stick them all over your document.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks ugly, but should work

```
  function ShowFeatures(evt) 
  {
    evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".IntroductionDiv")...
```

Comment: its full code or something i don't understand this !

Answer (score 0):

You can point your [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to a unique class name thanks to the `$userrow['id']`:

JavaScript:

```
function ShowIntroduction(id) {
    document.querySelector('.IntroductionDiv' + id).style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('.FeaturesDiv' + id).style.display = 'none';
}

function ShowFeatures(id) {
    document.querySelector('.IntroductionDiv' + id).style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.FeaturesDiv' + id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select)) : ?>
    <div class="MainOuterDiv" style="border:1px solid transparent;">
        <div class="DetailsCircleBtnDiv" >
            <a href="#" onClick="ShowIntroduction(<?php echo $userrow['id'] ?>);"> Introduction </a>
            <a href="#" onClick="ShowFeatures(<?php echo $userrow['id'] ?>);" style="margin-left:10px"> Features </a>
        </div> <!--- End of DetailsCircleBtnDiv -->
        </br>

        <div class="DetailsTextDiv">
            <div class="FeaturesDiv<?php echo $userrow['id'] ?>" style="border:1px solid black;">
                <p class="Products-Features-P" ><?php echo $userrow['features'] ?></p>
            </div></br>
            <div class="IntroductionDiv<?php echo $userrow['id'] ?>" style="border:1px solid black;">
                <p id="demo" class="Products-Introductio-P" ><?php echo $userrow['introduction'] ?></p>
            </div></br>
        </div> <!--- End of DetailsTextDiv -->
    </div> <!--- End of MainOuterDiv -->
    </br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Great its works because of "$id" is always unique and it identify onclick event always differently. Thanks @YosvelQuintero